# Got a dataset refresh problem with the PowerBI gateway on a Virtual Machine in Azure

Tags: powerbi, dataset, refresh, gateway

Something went wrong, see error message:

> Power BI may have lost connectivity with the data gateway during this dataset refresh. Please make sure that the data gateway is up and running for the next scheduled refresh.
> Please try again later or contact support. If you contact support, please provide these details.
>
> Cluster URIWABI-NORTH-EUROPE-redirect.analysis.windows.net
> Activity ID86fd62af-8eab-478c-b808-8c9bd2728142
> Request IDa4fb8d50-f156-9263-bc05-dc6081424ac0
> Time2022-11-28 09:18:33Z

I already:

- Installed the latest version of the Gateway server
- Restarted the gateway several times
- And strange enough sometimes, but really sometimes (1 of more than 50 times) a manual refresh works
- Problem occurs in dataset to SQLServer databases as well with datasets to files.
  Tried already refreshes with datasets only to SqlServer databases.

Someone familiar with this problem, or someone has better a solution?